# Null pointer exception launching debug (Unable to instantiate activity) . Bad IF condition?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have this piece of code.
When I launch debug I receive the error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{nicola.pokerstarsleaguecalculator/nicola.pokerstarsleaguecalculator.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a
>   null object reference.

I suppose the error is here:

```
if (JTIscritti.getText().length()!=0)
```

How can i correct it?
Thanks

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText JTIscritti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.JTIscritti);
    public TextView JLPremiati = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JLPremiati);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        JTIscritti.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            premiati();
            }
            public void premiati() {
                if (JTIscritti.getText().length()!=0) {
                    PuntiLeague aPunti = new PuntiLeague();
                    String strIscritti = String.valueOf(JTIscritti.getText());
                    int iscritti = Integer.parseInt((strIscritti));
                    int premiati = aPunti.aPremio(iscritti);
                    String strPremiati = Integer.toString(premiati);
                    JLPremiati.setText(strPremiati);
                }
                else JLPremiati.setText("0");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I solved thank to @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ and @VishnuSP moving some declarations+assignments

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText JTIscritti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.JTIscritti);
    final TextView JLPremiati = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JLPremiati);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        JTIscritti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.JTIscritti);
        JLPremiati = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JLPremiati);

       //----your code/logic----
}
```

Views will be created only after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

execution. Before that `findViewById' will return null.

Comment: Thank you  @VishnuSP  I moved Declaration and assignment after setContentView and declared them as final, and now It works

Answer (score 3):

You have to do this initialization

```
public EditText JTIscritti = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.JTIscritti);
public TextView JLPremiati = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.JLPremiati);
```

in the onCreate method, remember that before that callback the layout is not inflated/initialized giving as consequence that **JTIscritti** and **JLPremiati** will get initialized to a null reference, so doing this `JTIscritti.getText()` on a null reference will throw a NPE!

Comment: Thank you @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ . I flagged VishnuSP answer just because it was the first one.